# Adaptive Card QuickView Navigation not firing

Tags: sharepoint-online, adaptive-cards, spfx-extension

Ok, so I'm just getting started with adaptive cards and downloaded the PNP ACE project ([Git Hub Link](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-aces)) to use as a jumping off point.   Started the project up and ran gulp serve.... everything seemed great.... until I tried to click either the View Items or Add Item buttons on the CardView.  Both of these buttons fire QuickViews, but when you click them nothing happened.  Tried 2 different browsers, no errors registered in the console, it just acts like there isn't an action tied to the buttons.

So, thinking "*well maybe something got screwed up in a commit*", I started a brand new project using yeoman.

Got the project set up, building and served it up; EXACT SAME PROBLEM!!  The button in the default ACE project template didn't work either.  I can't figure out what gives.

Here is the function for the button that the template created :

```
public get cardButtons(): [ICardButton] | [ICardButton, ICardButton] | undefined {
return [
  {
    title: strings.QuickViewButton,
    action: {
      type: 'QuickView',
      parameters: {
        view: QUICK_VIEW_REGISTRY_ID
      }
    }
  }
]};
```

That looks just like the PNP example (and every other example I've seen online).   Even the quickViewNavigator is populated the same.  Here is the one from the template project (class definitions removed to save space):

```
const CARD_VIEW_REGISTRY_ID: string = 'JasonAdaptiveTest_CARD_VIEW';
export const QUICK_VIEW_REGISTRY_ID: string = 'JasonAdaptiveTest_QUICK_VIEW';

public onInit(): Promise<void> {
    this.state = { };

    this.cardNavigator.register(CARD_VIEW_REGISTRY_ID, () => new CardView());
    this.quickViewNavigator.register(QUICK_VIEW_REGISTRY_ID, () => new QuickView());

    return Promise.resolve();
  }
```

So what gives?  Why do these not work?   Is there some NPM package that may be missing?

Answer (score 0):

Well, found the line buried in the tutorials that explains my problem.  A single note, in a page that isn't necessarily about quick views.

> Note
>
> ACE interaction is disabled while in Edit mode. The Workbench or Page must be >in Preview or Read mode to interact with the ACE.